# SMTP not working with php mailer class

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have two accounts:

no-reply@weddinggrabs.com
no-reply@appovio.com

and

Incoming POP3: pop.secureserver.net (995)
Outgoing SMTP: smtpout.secureserver.net (80, 3535, 25, 465)

These work using email clients like Thunderbird, post-box, etc, but not with php-mailer:

```
        error_reporting(0);
        require_once ("class.phpmailer.php");// PHP MAILER FOR SENDING EMAILS

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        define('EMAIL_HOST','smtpout.secureserver.net');
        define('EMAIL_USER','no-reply@weddinggrabs.com');
        define('EMAIL_PASSWORD','xxxxxxxx');

        $mail->IsSMTP();                    
        $mail->Port     = 465;              
        $mail->Host     = EMAIL_HOST;       
        $mail->Username = EMAIL_USER;       
        $mail->Password = EMAIL_PASSWORD;   
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;             

        $mail->FromName = "Administrator";
        $mail->From = "Administrator";
        $mail->AddAddress($email); 
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;   
        $mail->IsHTML(true);    
        $mail->Subject  = "Seating Arrangements on Event";
        $mail->Body     = "Dear WeddingWire Customer";

        if($mail->Send()) return "true";        

        return  "false";
```

Comment: you are missing `if`'s closing bracket `)`. Is it a typo?

Comment: 1. You have syntax error in the file,2. Please comment   error_reporting(0); line to see if the code is able to get the correct path to the PHP mailer class

Comment: error_reporting(0); is just to hide all deprecated methods warning from php-mailer class. the file is included, object is created perfectly and without SMTP, isMail() function of php-mailer class sends mail. but I have to use SMTP and have to authenticate user.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the non-standard port of 465 instead of 25?

Comment: It is also possible that the PHP {{mail}} function has been disabled in {{php.ini}} by the web hosting provider.

Answer (score 7):

have u tried $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl' ? some SMTP servers need this.

Check the error with $mail->ErrorInfo sometime gives a tip.

Comment: Thanks, $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl' worked but $mail->SMTPSecure='tls' didn't work, that was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using this info you configure phpmailer like this:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // enables SMTP debug
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
```

I think this will be helpful for you. either it will be work or show the real issue comes in your mail.
If this not work then please check some things

1. Does your Host have permission to relay through the SMTP Host?
2. Does your host require POP before SMTP?
3. Does your Host require SMTP authentication?

Answer (score 0):

From the server hosting this file, does calling smtpout.secureserver.net resolve correctly?  Try pinging it and seeing if the IP address is what you expect

Barring that, I PHPMailer() uses exceptions if you pass it a "true" parameter, so try something like:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try
{
    $mail->IsSMTP();                    
    $mail->Port     = 465;              
    $mail->Host     = EMAIL_HOST;       
    $mail->Username = EMAIL_USER;       
    $mail->Password = EMAIL_PASSWORD;   
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;             

    $mail->FromName = "Administrator";
    $mail->From = "Administrator";
    $mail->AddAddress($email); 
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;   
    $mail->IsHTML(true);    
    $mail->Subject  = "Seating Arrangements on Event";
    $mail->Body     = "Dear WeddingWire Customer";
    $mail->Send();
} catch( phpmailerException $e ) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
    exit(0);
}
```

That should at lease give you an insight into the error being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$mailer->SmtpSend();` [This tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#External_SMTP_Servers_PHP_Mail) seems to suggest you need to.